# Jython saying "No visible constructors for class"

Tags: java, python, tomcat, servlets, jython

I have a jython servlet as part of a large application running in tomcat5. I tested a few Spring Framework classes and create the objects in the Jython servlet. When I try to create objects of classes in the application I catch an Exception message "No visible constructors for class". These java classes do have a public constructor class, such as:

`public SchoolImpl() {
    }`

I create the object in python:

`from com.dc.sports.entity import SchoolImpl`

`...`

`school = SchoolImpl()`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `SchoolImpl` a package-private or a public class?

Comment: Ahh, it looks like it is a package-private. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doublep / cluch  answered the question :-) in the comment

adding just a little info:

From the Jython FAQ :

**3.3   Why can't I execute a 'protected' or 'private' Java instance method or access a 'protected' or 'private' attribute in a Java package?**

By default, as in Java, these methods are protected from external access. Access to all Java fields and methods can be enabled with the python.security.respectJavaAccessibility registry setting:

```
# Setting this to false will allow Jython to provide access to
# non-public fields, methods, and constructors of Java objects.
python.security.respectJavaAccessibility = false
```

Comment: to see what is "registry": http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/registry.html I'm not sure if it still exists or not in 2.5.