# No Visible constructors for class when creating Java object in Jython

Tags: java, python, jython-2.5

I am running the Jython shell. I was trying to mess around with a few Java classes in the shell, as I am a bit new to using the Jython implementation. However, when I try to create an object, for example, I get the following Traceback.

```
>>> s = java.lang.annotation
>>> s.Annotation()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No visible constructors for class (java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
```

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065573/jython-saying-no-visible-constructors-for-class) and tried editing the `python.security.respectJavaAccessibility` line in my Jython registry to equal `false`, but that was to no avail.

What could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Annotation` is not a class, its an `interface` [[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html)] . You cannot instantiate an interface , you will have to create a class that implements the Annotation class and instantiate that class.